# Show local date format in MVC 6 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In a project based on the ASP.NET 5 Web Application Template, this property of the viewmodel

```
    [Display(Name = "Subscription Expires")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:D}")]
    public DateTime? SubscriptionExpires { get; set; }
```

when rendered by `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SubscriptionExpires)` in the view shows US date format regardless of the users locale.

How do I ensure dates are displayed in the in the users format?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture` exactly and what format you can see it in view?

Comment: When you say "system locale" do you actually mean "client locale"? I would hope the server locale would be irrelevant.

Comment: It's worth seeing whether https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET is still relevant - it may not be, but it's worth a look.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: 100% correct. Using 'D' will use the server's locale settings for code executing on the server.

Comment: I meant users locale not system locale and have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: My CurrentCulture is en-au (Australia). Short date should render as Tuesday 19 January 2016 but it renders as Tuesday January 19 2016

Comment: Even though my locale is en-au I see US date format when running the app locally in IIS Express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For setting the Date locale as of the RC2 build, you can use the below in your Startup.cs file within the Configure method:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        // Configure the Localization middleware
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {                    
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
            }
        });
```

Globalization is still not polished off AFAIK, you can find out some more info from this blog post which is correct as of RC1-final: [RC1-final Globalization](http://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/) and also the ASP.Net Localization repo on GitHub [Localization repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @an Auty. Isn't there some way to just render the client date format without specifying every culture we want to support? We would like clients to see their dates correctly regardless of where they are in the world.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my answer, Globalization in ASP.Net 5 is not currently polished off, and therefore what you're looking to achieve isn't easy. [Jerrie Pelser](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization) has put together a good blog post on how you can set/retrieve the current culture although it's for a previous beta build. I think currently what would be a nice solution is to write up your own middleware whereby you can get the culture language type from the URL and set the date format based on that.

Comment: Although there are a few ways in which to 'guess' where a user is browsing your site from, I don't believe any of them can be relied upon unless you use the HTML5 Geolocation, which has to be allowed by the user. Your alternative is to use the country code in the url and you can specify a date format based on that.